# Macro for Copy/Paste cells every nth to another workbook

Tags: excel, cells, vba

I'm looking to paste some cells from one closed workbook to another workbook.
I have managed to paste a couple of cells successfully, however, I want to copy cells starting at D9, and then every 9th until empty cells are found on SourceWb, and paste them in the other workbook TargetWb starting at column A, row 2, and so on horizontally (B2, C2, D2, etc)

```
Sub PullClosedData()

Dim filePath As String
Dim SourceWb As Workbook
Dim TargetWb As Workbook

Set TargetWb = ActiveWorkbook

filePath = TargetWb.Sheets("System").Range("A1").Value
Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)

SourceWb.Sheets("results").Range("D9").Copy 
Destination:=TargetWb.Sheets("Data").Range("A2")
SourceWb.Sheets("results").Range("D18").Copy 
Destination:=TargetWb.Sheets("Data").Range("B2")

SourceWb.Save
TargetWb.Save
TargetWb.Close False

MsgBox "Complete!"

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dynamic Variant Array, and dynamic range.

```
Sub PullClosedData()

Dim filePath As String
Dim SourceWb As Workbook
Dim TargetWb As Workbook
Dim sWs As Worksheet, tWs As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, n As Long, r As Long, vR() As Variant

Set TargetWb = ActiveWorkbook

filePath = TargetWb.Sheets("System").Range("A1").Value
Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
Set sWs = SourceWb.Sheets("resuts")
Set tWs = TargetWb.Sheets("Data")
With sWs
    r = .Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    For i = 9 To r Step 9
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)  '<~~ increase dynamic array.
        vR(n) = .Range("d" & i)
    Next i
End With
tWs.Range("a2").Resize(1, n) = vR


SourceWb.Save
TargetWb.Save
TargetWb.Close False

MsgBox "Complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer.

Comment: However, it throws a 1004 error, application-defined or object defined error. I added a "dot" before Rows but now it throws Type Mismatch Error 13.

Comment: @AlfredS,  Oh, I recognize now that you did not define filepath.